# A question about ownership of the Darksaber

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, the-mandalorian

In the final episode of season 2 of the the Mandalorian (“Chapter 16: The Rescue”) Moff Gideon makes a big thing of the fact that…

> …the Darksaber cannot just be passed on but needs to be won by defeating it's current rightful owner. For this reason Bo-Katan is not able to accept it when offered to her by Mando.

Why then it was previously passed from Sabine to Bo-Katan — during the *Rebels* series — in what to me seem like very similar circumstances.

Disney canon answers preferred, but I’m also interested in any relevant information from *Legends*, especially when it doesn’t contradict Disney canon.

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe while making the last episode of the Mandalorian Season 2 they missed that part, but you also have to remember that Sabine never won the DarkSaber in combat either. Ezra found it and gave it to her. The DarkSaber didn’t have an owner. A rightful owner that is. It technically didn’t truly belong to Sabine. So Bo Katan accepting the DarkSaber from Sabine in that episode of *Rebels* wasn’t really that off. Bo Katan was just accepting it because she knew that if she didn’t take it, then it would belong to Maul. Maul was the actual owner. He won it in combat with Pre Vizla. But Bo Katan believed that outsiders could not rule. That’s why she went rogue and didn’t follow Maul. Instead she started her own clan. But that’s most likely why she tools it from Sabine but not Din. She knew that it wasn’t rightfully Sabine's, and she believed that Maul didn’t have a right to it either because he wasn’t Mandalorian.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Mando, Sabine didn’t win it in combat. She and Ezra essentially found it in Maul’s cave on Dathomir.

She used it in battle freeing her father, but she wasn’t ready or willing to serve as ruler of Mandalore, so she passed it to someone who was worthy and willing and who had an otherwise legitimate claim… Bo-Katan.

Comment: I had to remind myself how Sabine got the Darksaber, she did find it but according to wookieepedia she also won rightful ownership "Sabine became the rightful wielder of the Darksaber after defeating Imperial Viceroy Gar Saxon in a duel."

Comment: This is conjecture, but Mando, like Sabine, also doesn't strike me as ready or willing to rule Mandalore.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, the "ridiculous name" is "Mjölnir", comes from the original Norse myths, and means "the grinder" or "the crusher", and may have originated in Proto-Indo-European referencing a divine thunder weapon. Its name is older than civilizations. Also, none of that was made up in comics, that's part of real human myth and legend. That "ridiculous name" is older than any of the languages we're currently using.

Comment: I disagree on this.  Sabine won the right to it in combat by beating Gar Saxon.  Her mother refused to acknowledge that the weapon belonged to Sabine until after she won.  So why did Bo-Katan keep it at that point Sabine gave it to her?